# Internet not working in browsers on mobile data, but works on WiFi and in all apps. Please help!

Tags: browser, connection-issues, mobile-data, lenovo

I get the error "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" in Chrome along with the message "This site cannot be reached" when I am on a mobile network. However, all apps, such as New York Times, The Guardian, etc. work fine and can download and display content just fine.

If I switch on the Wf-Fi, then internet works both in apps and in the browser.

I have also tried using Firefox and Opera, but I get the same issue.

Incidentally, the Gmail app behaves the same as the browsers: It cannot connect to the internet when on mobile networks.

I am using a Lenovo tablet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. that happens with Google Chrome over WIFI i have internet and can use YouTube App but the Browser isn't working.

I resolved the problem by removing Chrome and installing it again.

The problem disappeared, but i noticed it happened again when i allowed " Enable data saver feature on Chrome's settings/Advanced Datsaver" Make sure you have it turned off.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you :) So when "Data Saver" was kept ON, the Chrome browser wasn't working when phone is connected to a WiFi network.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove proxy in apn setting it will work.
Settings->Mobile data ->access point code -> click on selected option -> remove proxy it will start working...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. After tons of goggling, I found that in APN there is a proxy set option. Somehow mine was set to some value. Once I nullified it, the browser started loading, mobile data as well. Proxy shouldn't be set to any values, either in mobile data or on wifi.

Answer (score -1):

Have you set your APN settings correctly? Go to your carrier's website and do some googling to find the correct APN settings for your network. Once you have found them, you should be able to enter them by going to
Settings>Mobile Networks>Access Point Names (APN) and creating one with the correct APN settings.

Comment: I had the same issue and it worked now after the APN update